# Issue with R Programming. Flipping a weighted coin

Tags: r

> Q: Perform 100 repetitions of the experiment of flipping the weighted coin 200 compute the fraction of heads for each experiment, and store the result in a vector y1.

I am using the function replicate but I run into a problem where it will only show me the percent of the 100 repetitions but not each individual flip.

Here is what I have so far.

```
x= (sample(c(0,1), size=200, prob=c(.10,.90), replace=TRUE))
replicate(x,100)
```

Comment: See `?replicate`. Looks like you are passing arguments in the wrong order.

Answer (score 4):

This will do: `y1 = rbinom(100,200,0.9)/200`

But if you want to use your initial logic:

`y1 = apply(replicate(100,sample(0:1, size=200, prob=c(.1,.9), rep=T)),2,sum)/200`